# Prove that $ab$ is perfect cube.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b$ be positive integers, $b<a$, such that $a^3+b^3+ab$ is divisible by $ab(a-b)$. Prove that $ab$ is perfect cube.

My try:
Let $a=dm$ and $b=dn$ such that $gcd(m,n)=1$. now $ab|(a^3+b^3+ab)$ so $ab|a^3+b^3$.

now, $\frac{d(m^3+n^3)}{(mn)}$ is an integer so both $m$ and $n$ divide $d$ since $gcd(m,n)=1$. Let $d=mnk$. Hence $a=m^2nk$ and $b=mn^2k$ so $ab=m^3n^3k^2$. finally we need to prove that $k$ is a perfect cube. I am not getting this. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were so close . The problem is that you didn't used the whole condition :

$$ab(a-b) \mid a^3+b^3+ab$$

You only used the fact that $ab \mid a^3+b^3+ab$.

We know that $a=dm=km^2n$ and $b=kn^2m$ so the condition is now :

$$k^3m^4n^4(m-n) \mid k^3m^6n^3+k^3n^6m^3+k^2m^3n^3$$ and now simplify it :

$$kmn(m-n) \mid km^3+kn^3+1$$but this means that : $$k \mid km^3+kn^3+1$$ or

$$k \mid 1$$

This proves that $k=1$ and then : $$ab=(mn)^3$$ is a perfect cube .